# Angular material dialog Ios issue

Tags: angular

I am using angular material dialog and ran into this issue on Iphone.
 I cant open multiple dialogs, when I open first ( its ok ), I am trying to open second ( over the first, not closing the first ), then nothing gonna happen, I mean nothing's happening, no errors, no second dialog.

So, its working good on linux, windows, android, but is not working on Iphone, dont know yet about Mac OS.

I use standart code like this:

```
openDialog(): void {
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px'
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  this.animal = result;
});
```

UPDATE:: Its bug in angular material, i found the same issue in the angular material github's issue called "nested dialog on IOS" and it was fixed only in the latest verion of angular material about one month or so ago, if you have the same issue only way to fix it that update angular material to version 5.* but thats also required angular version 5.

Comment: Angular Material supports the most recent two versions of all major browsers: Chrome (including Android), Firefox, Safari (including iOS), and IE11 / Edge. https://github.com/angular/material2 (bottom chapter)
I would double check which version you have just to be sure otherwise it's a bug.

Comment: i am using version 2.0.0-beta.12 for angular 4.3

Comment: Version of the safari browser ;)

Comment: its the latest on Iphone ) and ios 11

Comment: Then it's probably a bug and you can make issue on the github.